# Need help to get out of the exception jungle

Tags: c#, .net, exception, control-flow

I've googled for quiet a time now and I still don't know which exception to use in which scenario. I've read that it's bad practice to raise `SystemExceptions` in your own code, because those exception should better get raised by the CLR.

But well, now I want to know what `Exeption` I should raise in different scenarios. Let's say I have a method which gets invoked with an enum as Parameter. That isn't a very good example - it just came off the top of my head.

```
public enum CommandAppearance
{
    Button,
    Menu,
    NotSpecified
}

//...

public void PlaceButtons(CommandAppearance commandAppearance)
{
    switch(commandAppearance)
    {
        case CommandAppearance.Button:
            // do the placing
        case CommandAppearance.Menu:
            // do the placing
        case CommandAppearance.NotSpecified:
            throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The button must have a defined appearance!")
    }
}
```

What would it be here? Is there some kind of site, where I can get an overview? Are there any patterns which tell you what kind of exception to raise? I'd just need some tips at this topic, because I'm pretty unconfident with this.

I think raising just `new Exception()`s isn't good practice, either, is it?

Comment: +1 just for the title :)

Comment: It is not recommended to throw `new Exception()` because the caller of your method will have to catch all exception types and not just the specific ones thrown by your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example scenario, I would suggest either:

- `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the method supports ALL values in the enum and an invalid value is passed.
- `NotSupportedException` if the method supports a subset of the values in the enum.

Generally speaking, you want to make use of the exception types [See this list of exceptions in the .net framework](http://mobydisk.com/softdev/techinfo/dotnetexceptions.html) where possible and it makes sense, otherwise you want to introduce your own. This may involve adding a common application exception for your application and adding more specific ones which inherit from it.

e.g.

```
public class MyAppException : Exception
{
    // This would be used if none of the .net exceptions are appropriate and it is a 
    // generic application error which can't be handled differently to any other 
    // application error.
}

public class CustomerStatusInvalidException : MyAppException
{
    // This would be thrown if the customer status is invalid, it allows the calling
    // code to catch this exception specifically and handle it differently to other 
    // exceptions, alternatively it would also be caught by (catch MyAppException) if 
    // there is no (catch CustomerStatusInvalidException).
}
```

Comment: What exception would you use if you have a generic method and you switch over the `typeof(T)` And the passed `T` isn't supported?

Comment: I'd use NotSupportedException, or if possible, add a generic constraint on the method to restrict it to supported types if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is the best buid-in exception for this. Also [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) suggests it.
If you need some another.. then the single way is to [create the new special exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx) `CommandAppearanceIsNotSpecifiedException`.

Comment: I actually use the ReSharper. Where does this tool suggest exceptions? And well, I was not just targeted on the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`. As well I wanted to know if there exists a kind of an overview which exception to use in which situation.
I don't mean custom exceptions. Just for standard scenarios like this. The only thing we do usually is `Log.Error(ex); throw ex;` (Caliburn)

Comment: When you put `switch` operator with `enum` argument and set cursor inside it's body, ReSharper lets you to press `Alt+Enter` and generate `case`s. It suggests `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` for `default` branch. I would recommend you to remove `NotSpecified` item from `enum` because every value that is not `Button` or `Menu` means that `enum` value *is not specified*.

Comment: As I wrote, that wasn't a very good example. That isn't actual code I'm using.